# How are templates arguments resolved/deduced?

Tags: c++

While learning and experimenting with templates, I came across something I could not grasp fully.

```
class sample
{
    public:
        sample(int a = 0) {}
};

template <typename T1,typename T2>
void add(T1 a) // Replace T1 with T2 resolves compilation error.
{}

int main()
{
    add<sample>(3); 
    return 0;
}
```

The above code results in compilation error (both 03 and c++0x). But when I change the argument type of add from T1 to T2, it is ok. With nm, the prototype created is add(sample,int) [T1 = sample, T2 = int]. Why does the compilation fail with T1 as the argument type but not T2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two way to specify template arguments: explicitly or implicitly.

This would be explicit:

```
template<typename T>
void do_something(T value) {};

do_something<float>(6);  // T is float
```

This would be implicit:

```
int x;

do_something(x);  // since first argument is T and x is int, T is int
```

In your case:

```
template <typename T1,typename T2> void add(T1 a);
add<sample>(3);  // T1 is explcitly sample, T2 is unknown
```

Case 2:

```
template <typename T1,typename T2> void add(T2 a);
add<sample>(3);  // T1 is explcitly sample, T2 is implicitly int
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `sample` class can be implicitly created from an `int`. And thus, when you specify `<sample>` as a type argument, the `int` matches the first parameter, of type `<sample>`, **implicitly**, but `T2` is then undefined as it can't be deduced to any type.

This doesn't happen in the second case, because then you specify partially the types: `<sample>` specifies the type of `T1`, and an `int` can then be deduced for `T2`, and the template types are all deduced. Even if all the types aren't used, this is fine.